# submit button post not sent after using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have 3 separate forms each with their own submit buttons (removed all other lines of form code as not required):

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" name="postingTopicSub" id="postingTopicSub" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="button" name="submittopic" id="submittopic" value="Submit" onclick="topicPostSubmit();"/>

<form action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" name="postingTopicReply" id="postingTopicReply" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="button" name="submitreply" id="submitreply" value="Submit" onclick="replyPostSubmit();"/>

<form action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" name="postingTopicEdit" id="postingTopicEdit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="button" name="submitedit" id="submitedit" value="Submit" onclick="editPostSubmit();"/>
```

I am using Javascript to verify the form data is filled in before submitting however because using JavaScript the POST data from the button is not being sent.

JavaScript submit for each form:

```
document.getElementById("postingTopicSub").submit();
document.getElementById("postingTopicReply").submit();
document.getElementById("postingTopicEdit").submit();
```

On my data page I use isset to make the SQL queries run are for the correct form:

```
// User meets all conditions and posts a topic
    if (isset($_POST['topicID'], $_POST['subject'], $_POST['post_text'], $_SESSION['username'], $_POST['submittopic']) && !isset($_POST['forumID'])) {

// User meets all conditions and posts a reply
    if (isset($_POST['topicID'], $_POST['post_text'], $_SESSION['username'], $_POST['submitreply'], $_POST['forumID'], $_POST['subject'])) {

// User meets all conditions and edits a post
    if (isset($_POST['topicID'], $_POST['post_text'], $_SESSION['username'], $_POST['submitedit'], $_POST['forumID'], $_POST['postID'], $_POST['subject'])) {
```

My questions:

- Is there a way to keep my method of keeping the 3 SQL queries separate
  to the specific forms
- Is there a way to sent the POST of the submit even though it is being
  submitted through JavaScript?
- Is there another way that I just haven't seen.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Full form (without bbcodes)

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" name="postingTopicSub" id="postingTopicSub" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="topicID" id="topicID" value="<?php echo $topicID ?>"/>
       <div class="post-subject">
        Subject:
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" />
    </div>

    <div class="post-textarea">
        <textarea name="post_text" id="post_text" cols="100" rows="30"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="post-button">
        <input type="button" name="submittopic" id="submittopic" value="Submit" onclick="topicPostSubmit();"/> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Full JS for form validation:

```
function forumssubmit() 
{
    var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
    var text = document.getElementById("post_text").value;

    if(subject=="" || text=="")
    {
        alert('Please fill in the subject and text');
        return false;
    }
        return true;
}

function topicPostSubmit()
{
  if(forumssubmit())
  {
    document.getElementById("postingTopicSub").submit();
  }
}
```

EDIT2::

New js:

```
function forumssubmit() 
{
    var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
    var text = document.getElementById("post_text").value;

    if(subject=="" || text=="")
    {
        alert('Please fill in the subject and text');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function topicPostSubmit()
{
  if(forumssubmit())
  {
    //document.getElementById("postingTopicSub").submit();
    return true;
  }
}
```

New button:

```
<input type="button" name="submittopic" id="submittopic" value="Submit" onclick="return topicPostSubmit();"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really just "using Javascript to verify the form data is filled" you can add a *return* to the onclick's of your submit buttons. You'll then be able to use those for submitting the form instead of Javascript.

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" name="postingTopicSub" id="postingTopicSub" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="submit" name="submittopic" id="submittopic" value="Submit" onclick="return topicPostSubmit()"/>

<form action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" name="postingTopicReply" id="postingTopicReply" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="submit" name="submitreply" id="submitreply" value="Submit" onclick="return replyPostSubmit()"/>

<form action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" name="postingTopicEdit" id="postingTopicEdit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="submit" name="submitedit" id="submitedit" value="Submit" onclick="return editPostSubmit()"/>
```

Then in the javascript if you have a bad state return false.

```
function editPostSubmit(){
  if(data == 'bad')
    return false;

  return true;
}
```

I also want to make sure you're doing data validation on the backend. We don't want to allow SQL injection on your page.

Edit:
Updated your modified code.

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" name="postingTopicSub" id="postingTopicSub" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="topicID" id="topicID" value="<?php echo $topicID ?>"/>
   <div class="post-subject">
    Subject:
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" />
</div>

<div class="post-textarea">
    <textarea name="post_text" id="post_text" cols="100" rows="30"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="post-button">
    <input type="submit" name="submittopic" id="submittopic" value="Submit" onclick="return forumssubmit();"/> 
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I have added the html code of the form and js code to my original post. I use require_once '../includes/topicPost.php'; at the beginning of my page which contains the prepare statements etc that updates the database. Would you be able to let me know how to make sure it 'is done on the back end'?

Comment: @Matt My comment was on the "data page" that is running SQL. Validating data on the webpage is fine, but it needs to be validated a second time in your PHP. If you don't then someone could look at how your web page works and write their own that allows bad data to be submitted. Since you're inputting this data into the database, the data also needs to be scrubbed so that it's not vulnerable to someone submitting a query that displays, changes or removes data in the database (among other things).

Comment: I use strip_tags on the textarea when saving the string to a variable and then I use prepare, execute statements to update the table. What other validation should I use?

Comment: @Matt You should be pretty good then. Without having that code to look at I can't say for certain though. As for your original question, has the answer helped you get it working? Should probably open a second question if you want to talk about php data validation/db stuff.

Comment: I tried using return true if the data is not bad (swapping out the document.get...submit(); for return true) but nothing happens afterwards. I will make a new question in a bit to question the security thanks :)

Comment: Sorry @LAROmega maybe my description was simplifed too haha.. I have updated my OP with my changes. However as I said, the verifying of the text fields works but it doesn't do anything after this.

Comment: @Matt Ya sorry, I saw that after I responded, then deleted my comment. I've updated the answer with what you should need. You shouldn't need topicPostSubmit() at all.

Comment: I changed my button to just "return forumssubmit();" and still nothing is happening when pressing the button

Comment: Did you update the input type from button to submit?